# UCanAccess SQL Insert failing; query works fine in MS Access unexpected token (UcanaccessStatement.java:222)

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

This is my first attempt at building something in Java, and the end goal here is to simply import an excel file into a MS Access database.

I suspect there's some sort of data incompatibility error, or something that UCA is doing to clean queries, but I don't know enough about Java or UCanAccess to track it down.

Here's the query I have assembled, which runs fine to insert data in MS Access directly:

```
INSERT INTO XXXX_XA_Data_1 ([Date],[Fund Ticker],[Unique ID],[Cash & Cash Equiv],[Mkt Value of Security Holdings],[Today's Future Variation Margin],[Other Net Assets],[Total Net Assets],[Fund Shares],[NAV],[Fund Sales ($)],[Fund Sales (Shares)],[Fund Redemptions ($)],[Fund Redemptions (Shares)]) 
VALUES (#12/01/2001#,"XXXXX","00000000-XXXXX",0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000);
```

Some data has been replaced with X's and 0s, but all of the column names are the same.

I've tried several variants to see what will work, and I can get it to insert Fund Ticker, Unique ID and Cash & Cash Equiv. Based on these attempts, I'm thinking that the date format is breaking it, or some of the column names, but I can't find anyone else who's encountered this exact issue.

Here's the java:

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
db = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:" + path_db);
```

...

```
Statement s = db.createStatement();
try {
  int result = s.executeUpdate(rowquery);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the full trace:

```
[2016-02-18 13:37:29.053]: SQL Insert failed for item 1. Aborting with exception: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.3.1 unexpected token: [
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessStatement.java:222)
    at DailyImporter.main(DailyImporter.java:226)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: [
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.executeWrapped(ExecuteUpdate.java:67)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:152)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.execute(ExecuteUpdate.java:50)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessStatement.java:220)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: [
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.checkIsIdentifier(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readSimpleColumnName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readSimpleColumnNames(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Are there column names or other data format issues that need to be resolved here? Or libraries other than UCanAccess that can simply run SELECT/INSERT queries on a MS Access db?

Comment: Can you show the entire script together, particularly the append query statement and not on it so own? I suspect a space in front of `values` but cannot tell as you laid it out. And please break line to avoid horizontal scrolling.

Comment: The query is pasted directly from the console - it is exactly as it is being built and passed in the rowquery variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UCanAccess currently has difficulty parsing SQL statements with field names that include an apostrophe (a.k.a. "single quote" character) `'`, e.g.,

```java
sql = "INSERT INTO XXXX_XA_Data_1 ([Today's Future Variation Margin]) VALUES (1)";
```

The issue has been reported to the UCanAccess development team and is expected to be fixed in a future release of UCanAccess.

In the meantime, if you don't need to do any sophisticated SQL queries then you could `import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;` and use the Jackcess API directly. For example, to perform the equivalent of the INSERT statement above you could do

```java
String dbFileSpec = "C:/Users/Public/example.accdb";
try (Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File(dbFileSpec))) {
    Table tbl = db.getTable("XXXX_XA_Data_1");
    HashMap rowData = new HashMap();
    rowData.put("Today's Future Variation Margin", 1);
    tbl.addRowFromMap(rowData);
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you! The only remaining issue is that Access doesn't seem to "recognize" the new data - I can't find it with the MSAccess interface (most users will read the db this way). I know because attempting to run the insert twice throws an exception about violating the unique ids. Is there some way to ensure the metadata is updated as well when rows are added?

Comment: Jackcess does update all relevant metadata, but it does so without using the Access Database Engine so existing connections from MSACCESS.EXE are not notified. More details [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/help/thread/9fd6f244/#57dd).

Comment: Unfortunate, but I'm glad to hear it isn't just me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes,"single quote issue" happens, using ucanaccess, if there are both white spaces and single quotes in the column name (if there aren't white spaces, it works). Notice that, as a work-around, you can simply omit the single quotes in the column name in the insert statement and it will work.